# PDO rowCount не верно определяет затронутые строки при UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

К примеру, в таблице всего два поля text и id, и ситуация такая, что данные в поле text могут не измениться, но запрос должен быть выполнен в любом случае. rowCount , если данные остались прежними - возвращает затронутых строк '0'. Почему? Строка ведь все равно затронута. Есть какая либо возможность проверять успешное выполнение запроса в моем случае?

```
$sql = "UPDATE `table1` SET `text`=:text" WHERE `id`=:id";
    $stmt=$this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':text', $text);
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    var_dump($stmt->rowCount());
```

Comment: Странная у вас логика. Если строка не изменилась, то она не затронута. Поэтому rowCount показывает 0.

Comment: Но а как тогда понять что запрос выполнился, и в таблице есть эта строка, и строка есть такая... без дополнительных select ? Есть какая либо возможность проверять успешное выполнение запроса в моем случае?

Comment: Надо открыть [мануал](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#refsect1-pdostatement.execute-returnvalues) и увидеть что `execute` возвращает вам либо `true` либо `false`. Но это ж в мануал надо ходить, не царское дело, понимаю.

Comment: Он вернет true даже если такой записи там и не будет! И если вы мануал хорошо читаете, то мой вопрос пожалуйста тоже почитайте внимательнее.

Comment: Ну если вы хотите убедиться, что такая запись есть, перед `UPDATE` сделайте `SELECT`. Тут уже будет без вариантов

Comment: Мне надо именно без select дополнительного (

Comment: Сделайте поле в таблице, которое при любом запросе `UPDATE` будет гарантированно обновляться.